# Do items sell for more if they are socketed?

Tags: torchlight-2

If I have an item with sockets, if I fill those sockets does the item sell for more?

E.g.

[image]

Would that item be worth more if the specks were in the item or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes, they do

Here is the item without the specks:

[image]

And here is the item with the specks:

[image]

---

The difference in sell price is 110 Gold, which *(correct me on this)* is the sell price of the specks combined.

Comment: I think you'd get more money if you sold the gems separately but that makes sense since you can't actually separate the item from the gems yourself without destroying one or the other.